# Sql Server Select Only Date Part From DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have problem in Sql Server for select only date part from DateTime.

The value of DateTime is 2014-05-01 00:00:00.000.

If tried this query I don't have error and the output is correct:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2014-05-01 00:00:00.000',110)
2014-05-01
```

If tried this other query in the doTable:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    [n].[a2].[DOTABLE]
WHERE
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),data,110) > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, getdate())
ORDER BY
    data DESC;
```

I have this error:

```
SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 242 - 
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type 
resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

The version of SQL server is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (Intel X86)        
Oct 14 2005 00:33:37        
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation       
Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: )
```

I suppose I'm not doing right but I know why.

Comment: What is the format of the dates stored in the data column?

Comment: The format of the dates stored in the data column is datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following is a better way to do what you want:

```
where date >= dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, getdate()) - 1)
```

This truncates the current date to midnight yesterday, which I am guessing is what you really want.

For your method, try using format 120:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [n].[a2].[DOTABLE]
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), data, 120) > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, getdate())
ORDER BY data DESC;
```

You can do this on both sides:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [n].[a2].[DOTABLE]
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), data, 120) > CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DAY, - 1, getdate()), 120)
ORDER BY data DESC;
```

This format is YYYY-MM-DD which is useful for comparisons.

Then, upgrade SQL Server, and use the `date` data type instead.

Comment: thank you, but your query the output is null, but I have in dotable records with data `2014-09-30 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq . . . I don't see how that affects anything in my answer.

Comment: I personally love the dateadd/datediff method, and use it frequently. Substringing just feels dirty for this sort of thing.

Comment: @md4 . . . Personally, I abhor it.  Fortunately, I only very rarely have to use SQL Server prior to 2008.

Comment: I like its flexibility, it can be used for just about any time unit (months, minutes, hours, even weeks with a bit of care) and fits easily into `group by` clauses. Sure, `convert(date, ...)` is nicer for day-resolution, but that's all it can do.

Answer (score 0):

Verified your query in SQL server 2008. It's running fine may be a specific issue related to SQL server 2005 for conversion between varchar and date time.

You can add explicit conversion to date type here

```
 SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    [n].[a2].[DOTABLE]
WHERE
    CAST( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),data,110) as datetime) > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, getdate())

ORDER BY
    data DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the following conversion to zero out the date part you don't requre (in this case time):

```
declare @n int = datediff(day, 0, [some_datetime_col]);
```

The above part will return the number of days since SQL Server's epoch time, as an integer. Then, to finish off the conversion:

```
select dateadd(day, @n, 0);
```

This adds back that number of days, returning a `datetime` with no time portion. To apply it to your example:

```
where
    datediff(day, 0, data) > (datediff(day, 0, getdate()) - 1)
```

In your case, you don't need to do the conversion back to `datetime` as it's just a `where` clause; you can compare integers pretty efficiently and get the same result.

The added benefit of this method is that you can just as easily apply it to months (get first day of month, for example) and years. More care needs to be taken with weeks, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

why you convert date to varchar?

try this query

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [n].[a2].[DOTABLE]
WHERE data > DATEADD(DAY, - 1, getdate())
ORDER BY data DESC;
```

Comment: thank you, but your query the output is null, but I have in dotable records with data `2014-09-30 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq if you must catch date with 00:00:00.000 you can change condtition to >= or change getdate() to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP